# How to active the the menu nav-item in a custom view that extend the laravel-backpack layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-backpack

In the `PostCrudController` i did override the `create()` method to redirect to a custom view.

```
public function create(){
  return redirect()->route('posts.create');
}
```

the custom view extends the Backpack layout.

```
@extends(backpack_view('blank'))

@section('content')
 //content
@endsection
```

Is there a way to add the `active` class the `Posts` nav-item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work by default, if it's not;

Make sure your routes are correct, and there is no typo like;
`/admin/article/create`
`/admin/articles/create`

Miss usage of singular and plural may break the default behaviour.
But this is just an example, take a deep look at the links.

---

Btw, this is the code on backpack side that active side menu links

1. *First look for an exact match including the search string*

```js
var $curentPageLink = $navLinks.filter(
    function() { return $(this).attr('href') === full_url; }
);
```

2. *If not found, look for the link that starts with the url*

```js
if(!$curentPageLink.length > 0){
    $curentPageLink = $navLinks.filter( function() {
      if ($(this).attr('href').startsWith(full_url)) {
        return true;
      }

      if (full_url.startsWith($(this).attr('href'))) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    });
}
```

3. In the end it sets the class active to that link.

```js
$curentPageLink.each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```